# How to modify a vdproj for a Windows service to be associated with a custom account

Tags: c#, .net, installation, windows-installer

I have a plain vdproj deployment project I use to install a service I've written.  I want the installer to assign a certain user/pass to the service instead of, say, a local system account.

I've seen examples, but they seem to involve code, whereas my deployment project has *no* codes file.  Just the .vdproj file.

How can I make this happen?  Thanks.

Background: The service is a C#.NET service targeting framework 4.  The installer is just the stock installer/deployment project offered in VS2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the service process installer object of your Windows Service there is a property for Account which you can set to User.  Doing so will prompt for user credentials during the installation process.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceprocessinstaller.account.aspx

If you want to preseed the Account values you can set the Account type to user and then set the Username and Password properties.

Since the ServiceProcessInstaller is the actual component that installs the service (not the Visual Studio Deployment Project) your interface to the install process is in there.

Comment: One follow up question... So my idea is to pull the user/pass details out of a conf file.  Said conf file is in the install directory.  However, to know the install directory I usually pull a registry key value that possibly isn't written yet (as this is the ProjectInstaller).  Is there some way to get this path before ServiceProcessInstaller.Install() is called?  Thanks again.